# cannot write a remotely mounted file

Tags: server, permissions, security, ubuntu-core, sshfs

Before opening my nextcloud server to the internet i'm trying to harden its security by configuring its sshd_config file.
Its a ubuntu core server so i can edit files only through sshfs.

The thing is, when i use sshfs to mount the server file system on my desktop then try to edit the file from the mountpoint i chose, i get permission denied for writing that file. I can view the file and the whole mounted file system but cannot edit it, despite sudoing.

I tried sshfs with the -o allow_root argument and the -o uid=0,gid=0 which gave me no success.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Check the `mount` options do: `mount`. Is the filesystem mounted Read Only (`ro`)?

Comment: the output of mount for the file system are the following : (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other).
So it seems in read and write (rw)

Comment: What remote user did you connect as? allow_root is local to your system; the remote writes are *always* carried out as the user you logged in to the remote system as.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `sshfs user@example.com`, *all* writes are don as `user`, no matter what local user you do the modifications under.

Normal user accounts does not have access to modify system configuration files.